# Finding highest point relative to point data

Tags: qgis, point, dem, altitude

I'm very much a beginner with QGIS (3.10.4) and I'm still learning terminology etc so my understanding is currently quite basic. I'm trying to find out the highest point of a hill relative to a point. I have slope and aspect and height data extracted for each of my 600 points but is there a way how I can find out if a certain point is or isn't at the highest point of that hill? Hope that makes sense...

Comment: I'm not sure what "the highest point of a hill relative to a point" means. Do you mean the highest point that can be reached going only uphill from some given point? How are your hills defined? Do you have one elevation map for each hill for each of your 600 points?

Comment: Are you looking for the maximum elevation of all of your 600 points on a map?

Comment: Due to the QGIS fast development cycle, if it's possible, try to use the latest LTR release whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks all, I have points for coin hoards and want to see if they're buried at the highest elevation of the immediate landscape, I have a 50m DEM. Apologies for my lack of understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Add raster values to points (`set z from raster`), so your points know how high they are.

Step 2: Run `maximum("height field")` on your point layer in the field calculator creating a new field of the corresponding type containing the maximum value of the height field of all your points.

Step 3: Check whether the height of your current point of interest is the max height.

Comment: Thanks Erik I will try this.